# Specificity select li with css in mega drop down

Tags: html, css

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8hvY4/1)

The code does not work too well on fiddle but works fine everywhere else, so ignore the drop down being out of position.

My question is: How would I select the links with css in the div with the class "dropdownCats" to style them?

Comment: Can't you just do `.dropdownCats a`, or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Nope. The "#testNav" styles seem to override everything.

Comment: Ahh, yeah I noticed now. See my answer/updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8hvY4/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `id` of the containing `ul` followed by the usual class selector:

```
#navTest .dropdownCats a {  }
```

You need the `id` selector to make it more specific than the next most specific selector:

```
#navTest li a {  }
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8hvY4/2/) (hover over "Categories" and the appearing links are now red).